# How to initiate JQuery FullCalendar with a specific time slot in agendaDay view?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'd like to know if is possible to begin FullCalendar time slots in other time else 00:00?
I have an application where the user can choose FullCalendar slot duration (15 minutes, 30 minutes, or what the user want). The user can also define a range of time as available to make some commitments. The problem is: the agendada view slots begin in 00:00. Let's suppose that the user would register a range of available time to commitments that begins at 10:00 o' clock. Depending of the slots duration that the user choose the 10:00 o'clock line may be not showed. There is a manner to initiate FullCalendar slots at 10:00 o'clock, or another time, according my necessities?

Comment: In v1 we had the `firstHour` configuration.. It seems like it changed in v2.

Comment: I've found a part of the solution: I need to set the minTime property. The question is: how to set this property after the calendar has rendered? When the user change the day, I'd like to change the minTime property according  the time ranges that the user has registered.

Answer (score 0):

To change options when the calendar is already rendered you need to destroy the calendar first, change the option, then build the calendar again. You can do it like this:

```
//This is (a mockup of) the creation of the calendar
var conf = { slotMinutes: 30 };
$('#calendar').fullCalendar(conf);

//When you need to dynamically change one or more options
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy')
conf.scrollTime = '10:00:00';
$('#calendar').fullCalendar(conf);
```

Comment: I'm using this in dayRender function :   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').calendar.options.minTime = '10:00:00';
         
        
//$('#calendar').fullCalendar('render'); . If I uncomment //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('render'), the page has an error. It isn't working...

Comment: I need that the alterations works when the user changes the day. So, I wrote your line of code in the dayRender function. However, when I use methods like $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy') or $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render') inside the dayRender function, the page becomes blank, in consequence of an error, I supose. There is another way to update the properties of the calendar when the user changes the day?

Comment: @LeoPinheiroDeSouza No, it is not implemented (yet?). I guess you have the same data available before the dayRender function as in the dayRender function so you can move your logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by using the calendar as a function.

```
 function renderCalendar(min, max, slot) {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');  // this is used to refresh (destroy and recreate)
    var mintime = (min == "") ? '00:00:00'  : min;  // set user selected time else default time
    var maxtime = (max === "") ? '24:00:00'  : max; // set user selected time else default time
    var slotToDisplay = (slot === undefined) ? '00:10:00'  : slot;      // if slot is undefined then use default slot timing          

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
                },
                windowResize: true,
                allDaySlot: true,
                slotDuration: slotToDisplay,
                minTime: mintime,
                maxTime: maxtime,
                buttonIcons: false,
                editable: true,
                ...
             });
 }
```

Then when a user selects a time slot. you pass it to calendar like this.

```
 renderCalendar(10:30:00, 18:30:00, 00:10:00);  // you can pass time based on user selects the time.
```